# Possible register address error reading machine code to binary code?

Tags: binary, disassembly, opcode, machine-code

I'm working on this disassembling assignment and a bit confused.

> Disassemble the following machine code into operations and arguments,
>   e.g., ADD R1,R2,R3.Explain what the whole program does,either in plain
>   English or in C type of pseudo code Note: you need to make up unique
>   labels for your assembly code.

Add r:       Code

---

1. 0x00:        07 FF
2. 0x02:        06 08
3. 0x04:        28 08
4. 0x06:        38 02
5. 0x08:        02 47
6. 0x0A:        3C 00

[here's the simple processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss444.png)

w - Write back ALU output to register file
src1 - Address for first ALU operand
src2 - Address for second ALU operand
dst - Address in where output is written

Here are the opcodes used in the assignment

- ADD 0x0 R[src1] + R[src2]->R[dst]
- SUB 0x1 R[src1] – R[src2]->R[dst]
- BLEZ 0xA If R[src1] ≤ 0, branch to BAddr (The last 6 bits are the
  address)
- HALT 0xF

Here's what I got

- 0000 0111 1111 1111
- 0000 0110 0000 1000
- 0001 1000 0000 0008
- 0011 1000 0000 0001
- 0000 0001 0010 0111
- 0011 1110 0000 0000

I get confused here - 0000 0111 1111 1111 looking at the instruction table, it looks like the program is subtracting from the same register and placing the result in the same register. Am I right? I feel like it is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did not check your opcodes but what you are describing is one way of reseting register to zero. Which makes sense as you do not know what that register contains. Other times XOR operation is used to get the same result.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks for the help!